# Apportable install not running

Tags: php, python, apportable

After installing apportable, I'm no longer able to run the most basic terminal commands such as (ls, curl, sh). I now have to type in /bin/ls to run ls.

Also, when I try running apportable load, I'm getting the following: env: python: No such file or directory.

I've already ran (echo; echo PATH=~/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH) >> ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile to make sure apportable command line interface is in the same directory as my Xcode project. I can't even run the sample Spin project provided on apportable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have somehow gotten a corrupt PATH.  Please check that ~/.bash_profile sets a valid PATH.

You should also be able to type:

```
/bin/echo $PATH
```

to see what your path was set to.